# VB.NET changes to datagridview not saved if used in DataGridView1_CellValueChanged

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, save

I use datagridview in VB.NET

On button1_Click() I used bellow code to save changes made in grid to DB.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(Dadapter)

    conList.Open()
    Dadapter.Update(DSet, "myShop")
    DSet.AcceptChanges()
    conList.Close()

End Sub
```

THIS WORKS FINE.

But I need to save data when you edit cell & set the focus to another cell.
So I used code bellow.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged

    Dim nColumn As Integer
    Dim nRow As Integer

    nRow = e.RowIndex
    nColumn = e.ColumnIndex

    If Not IsDBNull(e.ColumnIndex) Then
        If e.RowIndex > -1 Then
            If nColumn = 1 Then '--Column ShopName----
                If IsDBNull(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value) 
                                                                      Then
                    MsgBox("Shop Name Should not be Empty.")
                Else
                    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(Dadapter)

                    conList.Open()
                    Dadapter.Update(DSet, "myShop")
                    DSet.AcceptChanges()
                    conList.Close()
                End If
            End If

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

But data are not saved. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does your code make it into the `Else` block? Try `AcceptChanges()` before `Update()`.

Answer (score 1):

During cellValueChanged event, the dataset's HasChanges is still False. It seems that's why the database was not updated. You will need to call BeginEdit and EndEdit method of the data row.

Something like this

```
        Dim shopRow() As Data.DataRow
        shopRow = DSet.Tables(0).Select("UniqueID = " & id)
        shopRow(0).BeginEdit()
        shopRow(0).EndEdit()
```

This will change the hasChanges state to True.